# how to open another activity after using fade out animation?

Tags: java, android

I have tried to open another activity(in this code I use intentHello) after using fade in and fade out animation. But after fade out, it indicate to error and close application (Unfortunately Myapplication2 has stopped working). Here the code that I have used. Could somebody help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.ve.myapplication2;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
private ImageView image;
private Animation animFadeIn;
private Animation animFadeOut;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_fade_in);
    animFadeIn.setAnimationListener(this);
    animFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_fade_out);
    image.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
}
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

     Intent intentHello = new Intent(MainActivity.this, hello.class);
     startActivity(intentHello);

}
@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: Add your logcat as well

Comment: Also, check if your `hello` class is declared in Manifest